# Branch testing

Tags: testing

```
if(condition1)
    dosomething1();
if(condition2)
    dosomething2();
if(condition3)
    dosomething3();
```

Is it full branch testing if I have two test cases in this example

1. condition1 = condition2 = condition3 = true;
2. condition1 = condition2 = condition3 = false;

Or have I misunderstood it?
Trying to figure out the difference between branch and path testing. I get path testing so hope this is correct.

Comment: as below there are quite some different opinions on branch coverage and related testing meaasurements - here's something more on the subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Branch Testing:

> Testing in which all branches in the program source code are tested at least once.

Yes; you are performing correct branch testing, since all your branches are hit.  In fact you can remove your second test case, since case 1 executes all the branches.

Obviously branch testing is less encompassing than path testing, since it's likelyhood of hitting dependies is low and as such, ought not to be your only form of testing.

Comment: Hmm this confuses me? I get your definition but if i remove the secound testcase doesnt this just end up being statement coverage?

Comment: The second test case is redundant given the strict definition of branch testing... that is, the code before and after your if statements will get tested in case 1 and case 2.  Therefore case 2 isn't doing anything new.

Comment: Thank you! This site uses two testcases: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/03/02/statement-branch-and-path-coverage-testing-in-java.html?page=1

Comment: OK I dont get it. If I have done full statement coverage wouldnt I then also have full branch testing? How come branch testing is 'better'?

Comment: @bobjink - Branch testing, is merely stopping ground on the road to Path testing.

Comment: Ye I think I get branch testing. All branches has to be executed. But doesnt all branches contain statements, therefor making it almost identical to statement coverage?

Comment: Branch testing - have a testcase for every branch. The above example has three if's that have _one_ branch only. So one testcase is sufficient to cover them all. Don't mix it with decision coverage, that needs to make sure that you take every decision at least once - that needs two test cases! But of course they are closely related.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, Branch coverage is also known as Decision coverage and it covers both the true and false conditions

unlike the statement coverage. With an IF statement, the exit can either be TRUE or FALSE, depending on the value

of the logical condition that comes after IF.

Let us take one example to explain Branch coverage:

IF "A > B"

PRINT A is greater than B

ENDIF

So the Test Set for 100% branch coverage will be:

Test Case 1: A=5, B=2 which will return true.

Test Case 2: A=2, B=5 which will return false.

So in your case, both the test cases 1 and 2 are required for Branch coverage.

With only Test cases1, it will be statement coverage.

Answer (score 2):

**I disagree with the chosen answer that you can remove the second test line!** 
Wikipedia's definition of Branch testing states: 
"Branch coverage – Has each branch (also called DD-path) of each control structure (such as in if and case statements) been executed? **For example, given an if statement, have both the true and false branches been executed?** Another way of saying this is, has every edge in the program been executed?"
Link here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage

Also checkout this video lecture from Georgia Tech's Computer Science program on branch testing where this requirement is demonstrated in action. 
Link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkJFxPy08rk

Answer (score 1):

To achieve 100% basis path coverage, you need to define your basis set. The cyclomatic complexity of this method is four (one plus the number of decisions), so you need to define four linearly independent paths. To do this, you pick an arbitrary first path as a baseline, and then flip decisions one at a time until you have your basis set.

Path 1: Any path will do for your baseline, so pick true for the decisions' outcomes (represented as TTT). This is the first path in your basis set.

Path 2: To find the next basis path, flip the first decision (only) in your baseline, giving you FTT for your desired decision outcomes.

Path 3: You flip the second decision in your baseline path, giving you TFT for your third basis path. In this case, the first baseline decision remains fixed with the true outcome.

Path 4 : Finally, you flip the third decision in your baseline path, giving you TTF for your fourth basis path. In this case, the first baseline decision remains fixed with the true outcome.

So, your four basis paths are TTT, FTT, TFT, and TTF. Now, make up your tests and see what happens.

Remember, the goal of basis path testing is to test all decision outcomes independently of one another

(Extract from http://www.codign.com/pathbranchcode.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, then you may need eight test cases to completely cover the alternatives in the given code. For example, what if `dosomething2()` relies on some other state set up by `dosomething1()`? Your test cases would not catch that requirement.

Comment: Even so, 6? How did you get 8?

Comment: @Stefan: 2^3 = 8, which is the number of combinations of three binary bits: 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111.

Comment: @LFSR: Thanks, I wasn't able to find a definitive description of the difference by a quick google. One glossary I found defined them as exactly the same thing.

Comment: I think thats the point of testing. Branch testing wont always tell you that your program is right. I think what you are thinking about is path testing.

Comment: @Greg Wow. That's... thank you. One of the more glaring errors I've made this week.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you understand correctly.  Branch testing is just "all branches are executed."

Comment: So I don't need the secound testcase?